# Puppeteer code does not save a screenshot into my directory

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I am very new to this so I wanted to try the most basic sample code out there which is:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com',{waitUntil: 'load'});
  await page.screenshot({'Users/shreya/Desktop/test1/': 'example.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

The browser opens and closes google as expected but the 'example.png' does not get saved and I wonder if it even takes a screenshot.

Here is my package.json:

```json
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "day1.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "base64-img": "^1.0.4",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "mochawesome-report": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "puppeteer": "^14.4.1"
  }
}
```

In addition, I also get an ExperimentalAPI warning. I also want to mention that when downloading modules like mochawesome and mochawesome-report, I got a few warnings and vulnerabilities.

Comment: what kind of path are you giving, absolute or relative?

Comment: `'Users/shreya/Desktop/test1/': 'example.png'` should be `path: "example.png"`. When you omit the `"path"` key from the config object, nothing is saved, as the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions) say: "f no path is provided, the image won't be saved to the disk.".

Comment: @RinkeshP how do I know if it is absolute or relative? I am running it within the test1 directory..

Comment: @ggorlen this is the output i get: Error: Screenshots can only be written to a file path in a Node-like environment. at Page._Page_screenshotTask (/Users/shreya/Desktop/test1/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/commonPage.js:2632:23) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:26635) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Comment: How are you running this? The check you're faling is `typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.version` which validates that it's Node.

Comment: @ggorlen I run it on my mac terminal using 'node' command. So 'node file.js'

Comment: What's the output of `node -v`? I don't know why Puppeteer doesn't think you're running Node.

Comment: @sj443 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/ TLDR, if node cant find the path you have specified, it doesn't exist, so you would not see any output. The simplest thing that can be done is output in the same directory.

Comment: @ggorlen my node -v is 10.15.3 and my npm version is 6.4.1 - how do I update my npm if I need to?

Comment: Yeah, I'd update Node and npm. There are many posts on this for mac that will explain it better than I can in a comment.